# How to sort ASPxGridView column nulls last?

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

My dataset contains null values and - by default - null values ​​come first.

When sorting the data, how do I get null values ​​last?

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `OnColumnSort` event for your ASPxGridView as below:

```
protected void myGrid_CustomColumnSort(object sender, CustomColumnSortEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column == null)
        return;

    if (!e.Column.FieldName.ToString().Equals("myColumnFieldName"))
        return;

    if (e.Value1 == DBNull.Value || e.Value1 == null)
        e.Result = 1;
    else
        if (e.Value2 == DBNull.Value || e.Value2 == null)
            e.Result = -1;
        else
            e.Result = Comparer.Default.Compare(e.Value1, e.Value2);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

And set the `SortMode` attribute for yout column as:

```
<Settings SortMode="Custom" />
```